# Why doesn't VK_Control+VKHome work for me?

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TSell.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (Msg.Message=WM_KEYDOWN)and(Msg.wParam=VK_CONTROL+VK_HOME)then
     begin
 end;
```

Comment: What do you mean "work"? What happens, and what did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 10):

to check the status of the  VK_CONTROL virtual key, you must use the [`GetKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

try this sample

```
procedure TSell.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (Msg.Message=WM_KEYDOWN) then
   if  (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0) and (Msg.wParam=VK_HOME) then
    //do your stuff
end;
```

Comment: @Saeed: Welcome to StackOverflow. If @RRUZ's answer was the solution for your problem, please consider accepting it (using the checkmark on the left).

Comment: Note the difference between GetAsyncKeyState (you call this when you want to have the CURRENT state (Async)) or the state at the time the VK_HOME key was pressed (normal: GetKeyState). GetAsyncKeyState  info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 7):

`VK_CONTROL` + `VK_HOME` = 17 + 36 = 53 = `Ord('5')`. You're checking whether the user has pressed <kbd>5</kbd> along the top row of the keyboard. (Isn't that what you wanted? Your question didn't say.)

You can't just add the virtual-key codes of two independent keys to discover whether they're both being pressed simultaneously. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Home</kbd> are two different keys, and each one generates its own `wm_KeyDown` and `wm_KeyUp` messages. (But don't try to detect the pressing of both those keys in sequence. It will get far more complicated than you want. Detect when <kbd>Home</kbd> is pressed, and then use `GetKeyState`, like Rruz's answer demonstrates, to detect whether <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> was already down at the time you received the current keyboard message.)